# What was the inspiration for the Oriental Adventures classes?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, class

DnD Character Classes all have some observable [sources and influences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sources_and_influences_on_the_development_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Cleric):

In the Oriental Adventures books there are a bunch of new classes, including Samurai and and Wu Jen.

But what are the inspirations for some of these classes? In particular, the Wu Jen has always made me wonder. Are they just (dare I say it...) based off Asian stereotypes an given [funny nonsensical names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_mikado) or are they inspired by mythological and literary sources like their more Western counterparts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *wu jen* date back to the 1st edition **Oriental Adventures** sourcebook for AD&D. According to [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20101211030535/http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/24830973/Origins_of_the_words_Wu_Jen&post_num=4), it's the Wade-Giles romanization for what would probably now be rendered as wú rén (巫人) and translated as "sorcerer person." So it's a plausible name for the concept, but not one that predates D&D.

As for some of the other OA classes: the [sohei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C5%8Dhei) were Buddhist warrior monks; samurai, ninja, and yakuza are likely well known to you.